# Command "sudo rm \\" hangs - want to ensure no damage was done to system

Tags: linux, sudo, rm

I am trying to figure out what happened.  About an hour ago I was editing a file in /root using sudo but when I went to save and quit I accidentally hit the backslash key and wound up with a file in my own home directory called "\" owned by root with 640 permissions.  Knowing I couldn't remove the file using the name it was given I tried getting rid of it back escaping the backslash with another backslash `sudo rm \\`, however this seemed to cause the system to hang at which point I panicked and first tried a <kbd>Control-C</kbd> (which of course didn't work) and then a <kbd>Control-Z</kbd> which (after hitting the combination a couple of times) returned my prompt.

After ensuring I was in my home directory when I issued the original command, I decided to look for the process and sure enough it was still there in the list,  just paused.  I had to issue a `kill -9` in order to finally get rid of it, but I just want to make sure that it wasn't going anywhere else on the system deleting files. I can't think of another reason the command would have hung.

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming that the user tried to execute `sudo rm \`.

---

Typing any command, then `\` and <kbd>Enter</kbd> would do nothing.

It would do nothing, because you've just escaped a newline.  You probably got a new prompt that looked like `>`, right?  That's the secondary prompt (`$PS2`) and the shell uses it when it needs more data to complete the current command.

You will get it if you accidentally (or on purpose) do not close a quote, as in

```
$ echo 'hello
>
```

Continuing from there:

```
$ echo 'hello
> world'
hello
world
```

By typing `\` at the end of a line, you introduce a continuation line:

```
$ ls -l \
>
```

From there we may continue the previous line:

```
$ ls -l \
> /usr \
> /bin
```

When you later press <kbd>Enter</kbd> the newlines will converted into spaces and the command executed (as if you had typed `ls -l  /usr  /bin` in this case).

So, in conclusion:  You typed

```
$ sudo rm \
```

Then you pressed return.  This means that the command hasn't even been executed by the shell yet, because it's still waiting for you to end the command.  At this point, just press <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> to cancel the command.

The next question is: How to delete a file called `\`? (owned by root)

Like this:

```
$ sudo rm \\
```

or like this:

```
$ sudo rm '\'
```

Comment: Although the title of this question says ``sudo rm \\`` was run, I think this answer is probably correct. It explains the behavior that was observed. Maybe the OP typed ``sudo rm \``, pressed Enter, and *then* typed ``sudo rm \\``, intending it be run as a separate command but actually including it in the original command due to `\`'s line continuation.

Comment: @EliahKagan I went with what was said in the text itself.

Comment: Well, we both did, because the text they typed into their post body is different from what is rendered, due to ``\`` being treated specially here on Stack Exchange as well as in shells. The post's Markdown body has ``sudo rm \\`` as the command that was actually run, which is rendered as ``sudo rm \``, and it doesn't write ``\`` as ``\\`` elsewhere, suggesting the command really did have consecutive backslashes in it. However, the actual *behavior* the OP observed suggests your interpretation is correct.

Comment: @EliahKagan Well, we'll see if there is feedback.

Comment: Honest I did type "sudo rm \\" (that's two backslashes).  The command seemed to hang which is why I eventually managed to get out of it using "ctrl-x" and then had to kill -9 the process.  I don't know what it was doing but it wasn't waiting for more input.  From what I am reading it should have just deleted the file named "\" and returned the prompt.

Answer (score 0):

*This answer addresses the question in the title--and in the pre-rendered text of the question--about running `sudo rm \\`. Based on what you actually typed here on Unix.SE, it seems like this is what you ran. However, based on the behavior you observed, you may not have actually run that command, or even **any** command, [as Kusalananda explains](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/391232/11938). So I recommend you also read that answer. Either way, I think both answers should help assuage your concern (and perhaps that  of other readers) that you may have deleted other files. After all, part of the concern is not knowing exactly what was run.*

> I just want to make sure that it wasn't going anywhere else on the system deleting files

[Unless you passed](http://man.linuxtool.net/centos7/u3/man/1_rm.html) the `-r`, `-R`, or `--recursive` option to `rm`, it will not attempt to delete more than one file per filename operand that you have given it. Running `rm \\` in a shell passes `\` as a filename operand.

Sometimes you might pass something that looks like a single operand but it expands to multiple operands. This could happen, for example, if you used globbing characters like `*` or `?`. That is not something you have to worry about with `\\`.

Sometimes filenames start with `-` and can  be interpreted as options, which is why some commands, including `rm`, support a `--` option to indicate the end options. But that's not a concern in this case either. `\` starts with `\`, not `-`.

It is possible--though unlikely and also a *very bad idea*--that `rm` could be an alias or shell function that passes an option for recursive operation to `/bin/rm` rather than just running `/bin/rm`. You would probably know if you had done this. You have probably not done this. You can check, though. In most Bourne-style shells, including Bash which is what you're probably using on RHEL (also, you tagged [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)), you can run:

```
type rm
```

This will most likely show one of these:

```
rm is /bin/rm
```

```
rm is hashed (/bin/rm)
```

It may also show that `rm` is an alias that passes options like `-i` or `-I`  to  `rm`. So long as it doesn't pass `-r`,`-R`,  or `--recursive`, though,  it will not have attempted to delete multiple files other than the ones you've told it to delete.

The version of `rm` provided in GNU/Linux systems including Red Hat Enterprise Linux (you tagged [rhel](/questions/tagged/rhel)) is the one in GNU Coreutils. [You can read the Coreutils `rm` documentation here.](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#rm-invocation) Some distributions apply downstream patches but no such patch should change the basic operation of `rm` or add new ways to accidentally remove files recursively. The behavior of `rm` is basically the same across different Unix-like operating systems, and even if you hadn't said what OS you were running, the foregoing should apply.

Comment: So the output of "type rm" is as follows:  rm is a tracked alias for /bin/rm

I don't know why it hung or did nothing when I pressed enter after typing "sudo rm \\" but from what you're saying it should have just removed the file called "\" and returned the prompt.  I don't know why I after pausing it I had to "kill -9" it but it seemed to be the only way to remove the process.

Comment: @JTelep "rm is a tracked alias for /bin/rm" is what Ksh says; "rm is hahsed (/bin/rm)" is Bash. So that's fine. If `rm` aliased `rm -r`, `type rm` in Ksh would show "rm is an alias for 'rm -r'". If ``\`` exists, ``rm \\`` is a correct way to delete it. So yes, it should have removed the file or shown an error explaining why it couldn't. (You ran the command with `sudo`, but this shouldn't have affected the result, unless `sudo` refused to allow you to run it--but then `sudo` would show an error.) How did you find the PID to pass to `kill -9`? Do you know what the process name was? Was it `rm`?

Answer (score 0):

To remove a "tricky" filename, prefix it with `./`:

```
sudo rm ./\\
```

This can also be used if a teaser has added a funny file in your root `/`, like a file called **-rf ***:

```
cd /
sudo rm ./-rf\ \*
```

Without the `./` all your files would be gone.

Comment: Note that the last command removes _two_ files, `/-rf` and `/*`. It's better to use either `rm -- '-rf *'` or `rm './-rf *'` in this case.

Comment: You are right. Or `./-rf\ \*` which will be written with tab-completion after the first unique characters.

Comment: While the filename ``\`` is tricky in the sense that it must be quoted, it is not tricky in any of the ways affected by prepending `./` to it or passing `--` before it.